# the difference between sql and mysql and phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, phpmyadmin

I want to know the difference between sql and mysql and phpmyadmin
I will say what i understand about them and anyone can correct my wrong
I understand that

> Sql => is the language which help me to manipulate the data in
>   database  and help me to retrieve the data from database
>
> MySql => is the environment where the Sql language is run
>
> phpmyadmin => is web application contain MySql with GUI to make it
>   easy to the user to manage the database system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is quite correct.

Though I have also gathered good statements from the web, This is what it means:

**SQL**

> SQL (Structured Query Language) is a standardized programming language
>   that is used to manage relational databases and perform various
>   operations on the data in them.
>
> The uses of SQL include modifying database table and index structures;
>   adding, updating and deleting rows of data; and retrieving subsets of
>   information from within a database for transaction processing and
>   analytics applications.

**MySQL**

> MySQL is a freely available open-source(Backed by Oracle) Relational Database 
>   Management System (RDBMS) that uses Structured Query Language (SQL)

**phpMyAdmin**

> phpMyAdmin is a free and open-source tool written in PHP intended to
>   handle the administration of MySQL with the use of a web browser. It
>   can perform various tasks such as creating, modifying or deleting
>   databases, tables, fields or rows; executing SQL statements; or
>   managing users and permissions.

Cheers!!